# Get Document from child element

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In a web application context, is it possible and, if yes, how to get `Document` having a handle of some child element in a `UIMap`?
For example, my `UIMap` is something like
[image]

Having, for instance, `Link_Logout` handle, I need to go up in the tree and get `Document`. Thanks in advance.

To clarify a bit, I have a Telerik combo box control on a number of web pages, so I decided to create a simple custom class to handle the control. First I implemented it passing two params: UITestControl and string id:

```
    private UITestControl mDocument;
    private string mElementId;
    private HtmlDiv mDropDown;
    private HtmlEdit mEditBox;

    public TelerikComboBox(UITestControl document, String elementId)
    {
        mDocument = document;
        mElementId = elementId;

        mDropDown = new HtmlDiv(document);
        mDropDown.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId + "_DropDown", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        mEditBox = new HtmlEdit(document);
        mEditBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId + "_Input", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        mArrow = new HtmlHyperlink(document);
        mArrow.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId + "_Arrow", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
    }
```

To initialize it, I had to call

```
public static TelerikComboBox comboBox
{
    get { return new TelerikComboBox(new MainMenuMap().Window.Document, "ctl00_comonHeader_list"); }
}
```

In optimization purposes, I'd like to pass one single parameter - root div element, stored in UIMap:

```
public static TelerikComboBox myCombo
{
    get { return new TelerikComboBox(new MainMenuUIMap().Window.Document.MyTelerikCombo); }
}
```

. . .

```
public TelerikComboBox(HtmlDiv element)
    {
        mElementId = element.Id;
        mDropDown = new HtmlDiv(element);
        mDropDown.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId + "_DropDown", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        mEditBox = new HtmlEdit(element);
        mEditBox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId  + "_Input", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);

        mArrow = new HtmlHyperlink(element);
        mArrow.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, mElementId + "_Arrow", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains);
    }
```

The problem is that while "_Input" and "_Arrow" are inside the root  for the control, "_DropDown" part is put outside it in HTML, resulting in `Failed to find any control that matched the search condition` exception. So I thought maybe I could somehow go up the tree and retrieve `UITestControl Document` to avoid passing multiple params to the method.

Comment: The 'Document' control object should have a method called GetChildren() that returns a collection with all UITestControl children of the Document object. If this isn't what you wanted to know, could you clarify?

Comment: And if you just search without giving the parent container? The testrunner should be able to search 3 levels down with a small performance decrease.

Comment: removing parent container for mDropDown () seems to work. Scenario passed. However, removing parent from mEditBox doesn't work - exception `System.NotSupportedException` is thrown later on attempt to `if (!mEditBox.Text.Equals(text)) { ... }`. I'll leave only mDropDown without parent container specified and give it some testing. Thanks very much for the tip, Thomas

Comment: Well, this works only in IE. Chrome & FF cannot find the element if no parent provided.

Comment: Coded UI is not available for those browsers, you'd need [Selenium](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d/) components

Comment: Yes, that's what I use for cross-browsing